# PHP variables in HTML shows up as 'zero' in page title

Tags: php, html

I have a programming newbie. I am learning from the alphabets. Pardon me of my very basic questions. I have a HTML template inside a PHP gallery script. In the title tag of the HTML two variables are placed. `<title>"$gtitle $pcaption"</title>` ($gtitle is gallery title and $pcaption is photo caption)  My problem is `$pcaption` shows up as zero in the title tag of the page on the gallery page.It shows up in the title like

> "example gallery-0"

( I am thinking it is because $pcaption is empty on gallery page and when a picture is clicked the title tag shows up with the caption ). My question is, is there anyway to avoid the zero showing up?

I am working on a localhost and is using PHP 5.5.12.

My HTML part is below ( Sorry if this is full of mistakes )..

```
// Final Output
echo <<<__HTML_END
<html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<base href="/viewgallery.php/">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<!-- <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/> -->
<title><? php echo $gtitle . " " . $pcaption;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
<meta name="author" content="by .">
<meta name="Copyright" content="All rights reserved by .">  
<meta name="keywords" content="$p_keywords,Photography by .">
<meta name="title" content="$gallery_listing">
<meta name="description" content="$gallery_description,$pcaption.">
<link rel="image_src" href="/photos/$cname/$pcaption/">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 id="header1"><a href="/viewgallery.php"><span></span></a></h1>
<div class="main">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="/index.php">HOME&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
<li><a href="/viewgallery.php">MY GALLERIES&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
<li><a href="/searchmyway.php">SEARCH&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
<li><a href="/aboutme.php">ABOUT ME</a></li>
</ul>
$result_final
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="footinner">
<div id="seeker">
<form action="/searchmyway.php" method="get"><input type="text" name="q" id="search">
<input type="submit"  id="find" value="Search">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id:search" value="1">
</form></div></div>
<p class="footnote"> </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
__HTML_END;

?>
```

Thanks for any help...

EDIT - I have to admit this is not my own gallery script. I am trying to learn from this code. After looking at this for a long time. I see that there is an " echo " just above the HTML code. Looks like the final HTML is echoed out with the $results_final and I am trying to make changes after the echo command, may be that's where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: `<title><?php echo $gtitle . " " . $pcaption; ?></title>`

Comment: What is the content of `$pcaption` variable?

Comment: Do an if statement to check for empty for pcaption.

Comment: @martinezjc thank you..the content is a photo caption.

Comment: Showing us a wee bit more code would be nice, but not too much ;)

Comment: is this is the current output `"example gallery-0"` or just the output you spect?

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thank you I am going to add the HTML part to my question now. I am afraid it might be full of mistakes and my ignorance do not help! :) Your code seems to be the answer but when add that the whole PHP code shows up in the "page source". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @martinezjc yes this is the current output.

Comment: Ah, yes, the updated code helps a lot. Updated my answer. Heredoc changes things a bit because you can't (read: don't need to) open PHP tags inside of Heredoc. It just confuses it.

Comment: you not necessary have to make an echo for print all the html document, you can put php tags just in the places where it needs, i formatted your code and here is the result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7991250/ :)

Comment: In that setup, martinezjc, line 28 would need PHP tags around it otherwise it would print '$result_final' instead of evaluating the variable.

Comment: you're rigth there left php tags in the 28 line: `<?php echo $result_final; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$galleryTitle = $gtitle;
if(!empty($pcaption) && $pcaption > 0) { $galleryTitle .= " " . $pcaption; }
```

Put the 2 lines above right above the 'echo' line of your code and replace your title tag inside of that echo with the following.

```
<title>$galleryTitle</title>
```

That statement that is being echoed out is called a heredoc statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Ethan, thank you. I am learning a lot from all of you here. But can I ask what does your code literally means? To me it looks like it says, $galleryTitle=$gtitle if $pcaption is not empty and is greater than zero then concatenate $galleryTitle with $pcaption and a space? If I am not right , can you please explain this to me? This probably is very basic but steep learning curve for me.

Comment: You are spot on. Simple code that will accomplish what you need.

Comment: Ethan, can you try your code somewhere because when I try it, it is not concatenating $pcaption to $galleryTitle?. I even tried it on a test file with just this code and values. May be I am wrong..

Comment: Sorry! I got my concatenation mixed up. I spend too many days writing C#. Try the updated code. It should always be a '.' to join strings, not a '+'.

Comment: For some reason Ethan it still does not concatenate the $pcaption value. It is definitely displaying $gtitle value though. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Here's a Codepad: http://codepad.org/yrxQWdjb

This is the raw HTML, so just look at the rendered Title tags. Puts it together. Is pcaption being set as a string (with quotes) or as a number? If it is set as a string, remove [code]&& $pcaption > 0[/code] from my solution.

Comment: Ethan, thank you very much for helping me. I accepted your code as the answer. Thank you for your patience. pcaption is a string. That was the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a test -

```
if(0 == $pcaption) {
    echo '<title>' . $gtitle . '</title>';
} else {
    echo '<title>' . $gtitle . ' - ' . $pcaption . '</title>';
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to show the caption it if it is equal to 0 @martinezjc

Comment: [`My gold-plated 20-foot pole`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206934/php-variables-in-html-shows-up-as-zero-in-page-title#comment39257323_25206934) ;)

Comment: Jay, your answer makes sense to me. But when I try to place PHP code in the title the whole thing shows up as text in the HTML ( in the page view source ).

Comment: You should remove the title tag from your page and let the PHP above render it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if/then/else statement to accomplish this, something like:

```
echo "<title>".$gtitle;
if($pcaption != 0){echo " - ".$pcaption;}
echo "</title>";
```

You already know that you want to output your open and closing title tags and your $gtitle variable so you only need to write an if statement that checks the value of $pcaption and if it's not 0 then echo it. You might also want to add a check to see if $pcaption is empty (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as well, so your new if statement would be:

```
if($pcaption != 0 && !empty($pcaption)){...}
```

This way you don't end up out putting something like `<title>$gtitle - </title>` and having something that looks weird.

Comment: the_pete, thank you for your answer, your code made me think in a different way. Lots to learn from all of you guys...